# Open VB6 form design properties in a text file just like we have .Designer.vb file for VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration

I am working on a particular project where the VB6 forms need to be ported to VB.NET forms automatically. So to do that i need VB6 windows form design properties file. Is there any way to get the complete design properties of the form in the text file where it can be read. I have tried opening the form (i.e .frm extension) using notepad but cant get all the properties,It displays only few properties for a particular element.

Comment: I try to remember ... in the frm file only the "changed" properties are saved: everything you changed from the default value (in the form designer). Hope someone can verify this statement. I can only do that at home ... would last a few hourt until I can check it. But I warn you about some features of vb6: It´s not easy to translate control arrays to .NET

Comment: So you mean to say that only the properties which are changed from being default are only visible in the design properties when opened in editor.

Comment: Are these properties different for different element or the same like ForeColor Default value is it same for all the elements or differs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could open the `.frm` file in your explorer with an Text Editor like Notepad++.

In the top you will see the Designer code for this Form.

But you will see, that the code is not compatible with VB.NET.

Here an example for a VB6 Button:

```
Begin VB.CommandButton btnSaveFilter 
      Height          =   330
      HelpContextID   =   2283012
      Left            =   630
      MaskColor       =   &H00FF00FF&
      Picture         =   "frmMain.frx":08CC
      Style           =   1  
      TabIndex        =   31
      Top             =   6030
      UseMaskColor    =   -1  
      Width           =   330
End
```

Comment: Yea.I tried the same.But the issue is it doesnt give all the properties . Like for example for a form its backColor is ActiveBorder and the Label's BackColor is  ButtonFace. Its not showing me Label BackColor property in the Properties when i open in Notepad++.

Comment: Then the Property uses the default value.

Comment: Are these properties different for different element or the same like ForeColor Default value is it same for all the elements or differs?

Comment: I would say that the values are default for each control. When you use only the Microsoft controls and no 3rd Party Control then the Values should be the same. But other publisher could use other default values. For example different Font Styles.

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to the Visual Studio 2008 or earlier try the built-in [Upgrade Wizard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zc22a8x(v=vs.90).aspx). You can always upgrade to a later version once you have upgraded to Visual Basic 2008.

Migrating from VB6 to VB.Net can be a big task if you have a big program, and there are many different strategies. See the [`VB6-migration` tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vb6-migration/info) for more information.